# Does Safari have a timeout issue?

Tags: javascript, safari, timeout

I have a website that works fine in Firefox and IE but never finishes loading in Safari 4.0.4.

The live website loads a menu then loads a Google map. Using Safari, the Google map never loads.

I have a test website on the same server that uses the exact same code for loading a Google map and Safari can load the map (this is the one that won't load on my live web). This test website does not have the menu - only the Google map.

In both cases (live and test) the main web page calls a loadmap.js file.

I've been pulling everything apart to try to identify why Safari won't finish loading. Has anyone run across any problems/solutions with Safari that may help me find a resolution to this problem?

This is the site where I cannot see the Google map: http://appalachiantrail.rohland.org.

Comment: Do you get any Javascript errors?

Comment: Without seeing code or the broken page itself, I doubt anybody will be psychic enough to help out.

Comment: Have you tried the Developer Tools in Safari? You can see page errors, resource loading, and even debug javascript line-by-line. As Pointy pointed out (no pun intended), without seeing *any* code or link to your site, there's not much we can do to help....

Answer (score 0):

It's just a layout issue with your page in WebKit (the rendering engine in Safari and Google Chrome).  The map **is** loading, but the background is only being rendered a few px tall.  Try setting an explicit pixel height value on the `div#map_canvas`, instead of `height:98%`.